# Postgres - sensorthings

Tags: postgresql, sensorthings

am trying to connect a FROST database with postgres ( i want to access this database directly from pgdmin) and i have this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV5dI.png)

i add the ip adress on hba config but it won't work
those are the only info in frost server documentation : Database: PostgreSQL with PostGIS
The FROST-Server needs a database to store its data. Currently only PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extensions is supported.

Database installation
create PostgreSQL database for the data
install the postgis extensions in this database (CREATE EXTENSION postgis;)
Optional: If you want to use UUIDs as entity ids, you need the uuid-ossp extension (CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";)